# Passing an ArrayList of Java Objects While Calling a Stored Procedure Using Spring JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, spring-jdbc

What is the Right approach for passing an arraylist of java objects to a stored procedure. Internally the Stored procedure expects a collection of a particular data type . Currently i am trying the following but it is not working

example :

```
//Setting the JdbcCall Object
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new 
                  SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                  .withProcedureName("name")
                  .withCatalogName("catalog")
                  .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                  .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(
                  "input_parameter1", Types.ARRAY,
                  "SAMPLELIST"),
                  new SqlOutParameter("P_ERROR_MESSAGE"
                  , Types.VARCHAR));

//Creating the list of objects to be sent to proc
List<SampleObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
SampleObject obj = new SampleObject("some argument");
list.add(obj);

StructMapper<SimpleObject> mapper = new BeanPropertyStructMapper<>();

//Creating an Array From the Arraylist
SimpleObject[] objArray = list.toArray(new 
SimpleObject[list.size()]);

//Creating a Map to Store the input parameters for the proc
Map<String, Object> saveProcInputParams = new HashMap<>();

//Adding the List to the input Parameters
saveProcInputParams.put("input_parameter1",
                new SqlStructArrayValue<SimpleObject>( 
                objArray
                , mapper,
                "SAMPLEOBJECT",
                "SAMPLELIST"));                     

Map<String, Object> result = jdbcCall
            .execute(new 
            MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(saveProcInputParams));
```

SAMPLELIST is the List Type in the proc

SAMPLEOBJECT is the object struct type used in the proc

Comment: "it is not working" - please explain exactly what you mean here. Does your code do nothing?  Does it hang?  Does it put the wrong data in the database (and if so what does it put in and what should it)?  Does it report an error or throw an exception (and if so, what)?  Does it do something else?  Please also add the definition of the class `SimpleObject` and the Oracle types `SAMPLEOBJECT` and `SAMPLELIST`.